# How do I have to change my codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Whenever I want to click label, my sub level element displays that it's okay it's good as I want, but if I click checkbox (not label), my checkbox should be checked or by other means it has to be a filled check mark (and if I click label it my checkbox has to be empty check).

this post explainment from my last post and I guess this is impossible to do that and I have to change my structure to do what I want

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/zqoNQg)

my html

```
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>No Title</title>
    </head>
    <body> 

    <div class="my-checkbox">

     </div>

      <div class="new-checkbox">
        <ul>
          <li class="hasUl">
            <input type="checkbox" id="input1">
            <label for="input1">kategori <strong>(1)</strong>
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input11">
                <label for="input11">kategori<strong>(11)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input12">
                <label for="input12">kategori <strong>(12)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input13">
                <label for="input13">kategori <strong>(13)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input2">
            <label for="input2">kategori <strong>(2)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li class="hasUl">
            <input type="checkbox" id="input3">
            <label for="input3">kategori <strong>(3)</strong>
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input31">
                <label for="input31">kategori <strong>(31)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input32">
                <label for="input32">kategori <strong>(32)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input33">
                <label for="input33">kategori <strong>(33)</strong>
                </label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="input331">
                    <label for="input331">kategori <strong>(331)</strong>
                    </label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="input332">
                    <label for="input332">kategori <strong>(332)</strong>
                    </label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="input333">
                    <label for="input333">kategori <strong>(333)</strong>
                    </label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- new checkbox-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

my css

```
 .new-checkbox ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      margin-left: 30px;
      font: normal 11px/16px"Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
    }
    .new-checkbox ul:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .new-checkbox ul li {
      margin: 3px 0;
    }
    .new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
      display: none;
    }
    .new-checkbox label {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
      border: 1px solid #ffffff;
      content: "\00a0";
      display: inline-block;
      font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
      height: 13px;
      width: 13px;
      margin: 2px .25em 0 0;
      padding: 0;
      vertical-align: top;
      border: solid 1px #1375b3;
      color: #1375b3;
      opacity: .50;
    }
    .new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
      background: #fff;
      color: #1375b3;
      content: "\2714";
      text-align: center;
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .additional:before{
       border: 1px solid #ffffff;
      content: "\00a0" !important;
      display: inline-block;
      font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
      height: 13px;
      width: 13px;
      margin: 2px .25em 0 0;
      padding: 0;
      vertical-align: top;
      border: solid 1px #1375b3;
      color: #1375b3;
      opacity: .50;
    }
    .new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .new-checkbox ul li:before {
      content: "\25b6";
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 2px 0 0;
      width: 13px;
      height: 13px;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;
      color: #e74c3c;
      font-size: 8px;
      line-height: 13px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    li.parent.has-checked:before {
      content: "\25bc" !important;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 2px 0 0;
      width: 13px;
      height: 13px;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;
      color: #e74c3c;
      font-size: 8px;
      line-height: 13px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .new-checkbox li {
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    .new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"][id]:checked ~ li::before {
      content: "\25bc";
    }
    .new-checkbox li ul {
      display: none;
    }
    .new-checkbox li.has-checked  > ul {
      display: block;
    }
```

and my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.new-checkbox li:has(ul)').addClass('parent');

  $(".new-checkbox li.hasUl > label:not(:input[type='checkbox'])").on("click",function(){
     $(this).addClass("additional");
  });
  $('.new-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:not(label)').on("change", function() {
    var checked = this.checked,
      $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', checked).parent().toggleClass('has-checked', checked);

    $li.parentsUntil('.new-checkbox', 'li').each(function() {
      var $checks = $(this).find('ul input[type=checkbox]');
      $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', !$checks.filter(':not(:checked)').length);

      $(this).toggleClass('has-checked', $checks.is(':checked'));
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No JavaScript needed:

```css
.check-toggle input[type=checkbox] + label + div{
  display:none;
}
.check-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + div{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-id">
  <label for="my-id">Check me</label>
  <div>
    Some content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bu if I click label checkbox will be checked..no I don't want to this.I want to if I click checkbox it must be check mark or if I click label sub level ul has to be display :)

Comment: @fortherest It sounds like you're using label incorrectly. Use label to check the checkbox. If you want other behaviour, use a separate button or monitor when the input is changed.

Comment: I'm new on css and jquery and I don't know how to do it and I guess I have to fix with present structure so thanks

Comment: @fortherest No problem. Also, CSS can show/hide elements depending on whether an input is checked

Comment: as I said unfortanetly I'm a beginner and I have this structure I have to to this on it to fix if I create again I'm gonna write js and css stracth and it hardly of me for now

Comment: @fortherest See my updated answer for a way to toggle the div that immediately follows the label, using just CSS. Please accept the answer if that's what you wanted.